# ng-disable button function never getting called

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I see a lot of questions that look like duplicates to this but I am not seeing what I need from them.

So I have an angular component:

```
@Component({
 providers: [
 FlowsheetService,
 SubscriptionService
 ],
 moduleId: module.id,
 selector: 'flowsheet',
 templateUrl: './flowsheet.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['i-o-renderer.css'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

it implements a public function that returns boolean.

```
public ableToRetrieveHistoricalData() {
    return true;
}
```

the above function never gets called but the button click function gets called.

the HML page is:

```
<div>
    <div style="height: 10%; padding: 10px;">
        <span style="padding-left: 50px;">
                <button (click)="retrieveHistoricalData()" ng-disabled="ableToRetrieveHistoricalData()"> << Previous</button>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using Angular2+ , use `[disabled]` instead of `ng-disabled`.

```
<button (click)="retrieveHistoricalData()" 
[disabled]="ableToRetrieveHistoricalData()"> << Previous</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is << Previous really in the HTML? If so, I suspect that's confusing Angular. I'd try removing the << to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten that you are in angular2 app, you should use **`[disabled]`** instead of **`ng-disabled`** which is used in angular1 version

```
   <button (click)="retrieveHistoricalData()" [disabled]="ableToRetrieveHistoricalData()">  Previous</button>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/sdEblTsFtis7wHnzxIXS?p=preview)**